# Getting "Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are []"

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding

I have been through Stack Overflow and followed [an online tutorial](http://taciturndiscourse.com/services/ssl-for-webhttpbinding/) for SSL And WebHttpBinding.

I am getting back the same error as mentioned there. I have reverted back to the old web config as shown below. My https site is working fine, and I added my WCF as part of the site to avoid having to open a new port.

I'm trying to reach something like this now when I get the error:

> `https://localhost/_vti_bin/TestingSQL/sample.svc/mex`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="SharePointBits.Samples.WCFService.SampleService" behaviorConfiguration="SharePointBits.Samples.WCFService.SampleServiceBehavior">
<host> 
<baseAddresses> 
            <add baseAddress="https://testsite/_vti_bin/TestingSQL/Sample.svc"/> 
        </baseAddresses> 
    </host>

    <endpoint address="https://localhost/_vti_bin/TestingSQL/Sample.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SharePointBits.Samples.WCFService.ISampleService" 
bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingEndpointBinding">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SharePointBits.Samples.WCFService.SampleServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
    <!--<behavior name="">-->
      <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />-->
    <!--</behavior>-->
  </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>'
```

After I added my web address a new error occurs:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the
>   endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpsBinding. Registered base
>   address schemes are [].

I tried both ways and both have errors.

Adding an absolute address to `metadatabinding` gets me this error:

> The HttpsGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true
>   and the HttpsGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no
>   https base address.  Either supply an https base address or set
>   HttpsGetUrl to an absolute address.

Using the base address I get this error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the
>   endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpsBinding. Registered base
>   address schemes are [].

**Note**: I have changed the code above using the base address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a MEX endpoint with an address that makes WCF think it's relative, but you haven't provided a base address. Change the MEX endpoint for example to:

```
<endpoint address="https://testsite/_vti_bin/TestingSQL/mex" 
          binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Either that, or specify a [BaseAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788982.aspx) and use that on your endpoints.

In addition, you may want to tweak the [serviceMetaData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx) element, specifically the httpsGetUrl.

Comment: I have tried both way and it doesnt works and I am puzzled about base address. I attempted changing my endpoint to "" after adding base address but it gave me error of endpoint being empty, shouldn't it refer to base address? Did I place at wrong location? I referred to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734786.aspx

Comment: Fair enough. Have you tried tweaking the [serviceMetaData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx) element yet? Specifically the httpsGetUrl? Or tried temporarily removing the MEX endpoint?

Comment: Yes! you are right! Adding httpsGetUrl works and my endpoint is wrong, I included my service file name which has been giving error stating url is already registered. Thanks alot for your time! Thanks!